normalisation for modelling on new data
I have a model based on several environmental variables and I want to apply it to a new dataset/location but the variables, while theoretically measuring the same things (slope, riverwidth, streampower) differ from the original data in terms of range, distribution etc. quite considerably.
Could I normalise the original dataset in some way e.g. transform to between 0 - 1, remake the model on the converted dataset then apply the model to similarly normalised versions of the new dataset?
